# Quickfix for creating field variable - how to get back

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to get back to my previous caret position after i do a quick fix for create Field on a variable?

```
test = new String();
```

My caret is on "test" and i press ALT+ENTER -> create field 'test'
caret goes up to the top of the class and i can edit the Type then i press TAB to get to the name of the variable but after that i only can press ENTER and i don't go back to my line in the code.

I tried ENTER, TAB, ESCAPE.

Refactoring to Field works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Intellij shortcut for navigating to last cursor location.

- Mac: Alt + Command + Left Arrow
- Win: Alt + Control + Left Arrow

[image]

Similarly, you can also cycle forward to the last cursor location using

- Mac: Alt + Command + Right Arrow
- Win: Alt + Control + Right Arrow